# php55w-mysql not listed in webtatic repo

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos5

My server is Centos 5

I do the following instruction from Webtatic: https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

CentOS/RHEL 5.x:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm
```

But when run this command for installing php55w-mysql ext for my current php55w, it shows this log:

```
[root@centos ~]# yum install php55w-mysql --enablerepo=webtatic
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn
 * base: mirror.digistar.vn
 * extras: centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn
 * update: centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Install Process
No package php55w-mysql available.
Nothing to do
```

Then I try to list available package from webtatic repo:

```
[root@centos ~]# yum  --enablerepo=webtatic list | grep php
php55w.x86_64                            5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-cli.x86_64                        5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-common.x86_64                     5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-devel.x86_64                      5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-gd.x86_64                         5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-mbstring.x86_64                   5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-mcrypt.x86_64                     5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-pdo.x86_64                        5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-process.x86_64                    5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-pspell.x86_64                     5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
php55w-xml.x86_64                        5.5.11-1.w5                   installed
graphviz-php.x86_64                      2.12-8.el5.centos             extras
php.x86_64                               5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-bcmath.x86_64                        5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-cli.x86_64                           5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-common.x86_64                        5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-dba.x86_64                           5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-dbase.x86_64                         5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1         extras
php-devel.x86_64                         5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-eaccelerator.x86_64                  1:0.9.6.1-1.1.w5              webtatic
php-embedded.x86_64                      5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-fpm.x86_64                           5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-gd.x86_64                            5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-imap.x86_64                          5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-intl.x86_64                          5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-ldap.x86_64                          5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-mbstring.x86_64                      5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-mcrypt.x86_64                        5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-mhash.x86_64                         5.2.17-1.1.w5                 webtatic
php-mssql.x86_64                         5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-mysql.x86_64                         5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-ncurses.x86_64                       5.2.17-1.1.w5                 webtatic
php-odbc.x86_64                          5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-pdo.x86_64                           5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-pear.noarch                          1:1.9.4-1.w5                  webtatic
php-pear-Auth-SASL.noarch                1.0.2-4.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-DB.noarch                       1.7.13-1.el5.centos           extras
php-pear-Date.noarch                     1.4.7-2.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-File.noarch                     1.2.2-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-HTTP-Request.noarch             1.4.2-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-Log.noarch                      1.9.13-1.el5.centos           extras
php-pear-MDB2.noarch                     2.4.1-2.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-MDB2-Driver-mysql.noarch        1.4.1-3.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-Mail.noarch                     1.1.14-1.el5.centos           extras
php-pear-Mail-Mime.noarch                1.4.0-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-Net-SMTP.noarch                 1.2.10-1.el5.centos           extras
php-pear-Net-Sieve.noarch                1.1.5-2.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-Net-Socket.noarch               1.0.8-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-Net-URL.noarch                  1.0.15-1.el5.centos           extras
php-pecl-Fileinfo.x86_64                 1.0.4-3.el5.centos            extras
php-pecl-apc.x86_64                      3.1.9-1.2.w5                  webtatic
php-pecl-gearman.x86_64                  0.7.0-1.w5                    webtatic
php-pecl-memcache.x86_64                 3.0.7-1.w5                    webtatic
php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64                   2.1.0-1.w5                    webtatic
php-pgsql.x86_64                         5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-process.x86_64                       5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-pspell.x86_64                        5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-readline.x86_64                      5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1         extras
php-recode.x86_64                        5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-snmp.x86_64                          5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-soap.x86_64                          5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-suhosin.x86_64                       0.9.32.1-1.w5                 webtatic
php-tidy.x86_64                          5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-xhp.x86_64                           1.3.9-1.w5                    webtatic
php-xml.x86_64                           5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-xmlrpc.x86_64                        5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php-zts.x86_64                           5.3.28-4.w5                   webtatic
php53.x86_64                             5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-bcmath.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-cli.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-common.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-dba.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-devel.x86_64                       5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-gd.x86_64                          5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-imap.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-intl.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-ldap.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-mbstring.x86_64                    5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-mysql.x86_64                       5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-odbc.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-odbc64.x86_64                      5.3.3-2.el5                   base
php53-pdo.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-pgsql.x86_64                       5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-process.x86_64                     5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-pspell.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-snmp.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-soap.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-xml.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
php53-xmlrpc.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10               update
```

and the result not listed php55w-mysql !!!

**Update: The solution is**

First remove the old webtatic package, use command:

```
rpm -e webtatic5-release-5.1-3.noarch
```

then install it again, and

```
yum  --enablerepo=webtatic-el5 list | grep php
```

will show the full list of php55w packages

```
[root@centos ~]# yum --enablerepo=webtatic-el5 list | grep php
php55w.x86_64                            5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-cli.x86_64                        5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-common.x86_64                     5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-devel.x86_64                      5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-gd.x86_64                         5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-mbstring.x86_64                   5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-mcrypt.x86_64                     5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-mysql.x86_64                      5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-pdo.x86_64                        5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-process.x86_64                    5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-pspell.x86_64                     5.5.14-1.w5                installed
php55w-xml.x86_64                        5.5.14-1.w5                installed
graphviz-php.x86_64                      2.12-8.el5.centos          extras
php.x86_64                               5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-bcmath.x86_64                        5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-cli.x86_64                           5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-common.x86_64                        5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-dba.x86_64                           5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-dbase.x86_64                         5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1      extras
php-devel.x86_64                         5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-gd.x86_64                            5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-imap.x86_64                          5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-ldap.x86_64                          5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-mbstring.x86_64                      5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-mcrypt.x86_64                        5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1      extras
php-mhash.x86_64                         5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1      extras
php-mssql.x86_64                         5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1      extras
php-mysql.x86_64                         5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-ncurses.x86_64                       5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-odbc.x86_64                          5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-pdo.x86_64                           5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-pear.noarch                          1:1.4.9-8.el5              base
php-pear-Auth-SASL.noarch                1.0.2-4.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-DB.noarch                       1.7.13-1.el5.centos        extras
php-pear-Date.noarch                     1.4.7-2.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-File.noarch                     1.2.2-1.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-HTTP-Request.noarch             1.4.2-1.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-Log.noarch                      1.9.13-1.el5.centos        extras
php-pear-MDB2.noarch                     2.4.1-2.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-MDB2-Driver-mysql.noarch        1.4.1-3.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-Mail.noarch                     1.1.14-1.el5.centos        extras
php-pear-Mail-Mime.noarch                1.4.0-1.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-Net-SMTP.noarch                 1.2.10-1.el5.centos        extras
php-pear-Net-Sieve.noarch                1.1.5-2.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-Net-Socket.noarch               1.0.8-1.el5.centos         extras
php-pear-Net-URL.noarch                  1.0.15-1.el5.centos        extras
php-pecl-Fileinfo.x86_64                 1.0.4-3.el5.centos         extras
php-pecl-memcache.x86_64                 2.2.3-1.el5_2              extras
php-pgsql.x86_64                         5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-readline.x86_64                      5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1      extras
php-snmp.x86_64                          5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-soap.x86_64                          5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-tidy.x86_64                          5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1      extras
php-xml.x86_64                           5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php-xmlrpc.x86_64                        5.1.6-44.el5_10            update
php53.x86_64                             5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-bcmath.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-cli.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-common.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-dba.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-devel.x86_64                       5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-gd.x86_64                          5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-imap.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-intl.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-ldap.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-mbstring.x86_64                    5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-mysql.x86_64                       5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-odbc.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-odbc64.x86_64                      5.3.3-2.el5                base
php53-pdo.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-pgsql.x86_64                       5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-process.x86_64                     5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-pspell.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-snmp.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-soap.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-xml.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php53-xmlrpc.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10            update
php54w.x86_64                            5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-bcmath.x86_64                     5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-cli.x86_64                        5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-common.x86_64                     5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-dba.x86_64                        5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-devel.x86_64                      5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-embedded.x86_64                   5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-enchant.x86_64                    5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-fpm.x86_64                        5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-gd.x86_64                         5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-imap.x86_64                       5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-interbase.x86_64                  5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-intl.x86_64                       5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-ldap.x86_64                       5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-mbstring.x86_64                   5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-mcrypt.x86_64                     5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-mssql.x86_64                      5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-mysql.x86_64                      5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-mysqlnd.x86_64                    5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-odbc.x86_64                       5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-pdo.x86_64                        5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-pear.noarch                       1:1.9.4-7.w5               webtatic-el5
php54w-pecl-apc.x86_64                   3.1.13-3.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-pecl-apcu.x86_64                  4.0.6-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php54w-pecl-apcu-devel.x86_64            4.0.6-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php54w-pecl-gearman.x86_64               1.1.2-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php54w-pecl-memcache.x86_64              3.0.8-2.w5                 webtatic-el5
php54w-pecl-xdebug.x86_64                2.2.5-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php54w-pecl-zendopcache.x86_64           7.0.3-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php54w-pgsql.x86_64                      5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-process.x86_64                    5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-pspell.x86_64                     5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-recode.x86_64                     5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-snmp.x86_64                       5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-soap.x86_64                       5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-tidy.x86_64                       5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-xml.x86_64                        5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php54w-xmlrpc.x86_64                     5.4.30-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-bcmath.x86_64                     5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-dba.x86_64                        5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-embedded.x86_64                   5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-enchant.x86_64                    5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-fpm.x86_64                        5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-imap.x86_64                       5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-interbase.x86_64                  5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-intl.x86_64                       5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-ldap.x86_64                       5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-mssql.x86_64                      5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-mysqlnd.x86_64                    5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-odbc.x86_64                       5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-opcache.x86_64                    5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-pear.noarch                       1:1.9.4-7.w5               webtatic-el5
php55w-pecl-apcu.x86_64                  4.0.6-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php55w-pecl-apcu-devel.x86_64            4.0.6-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php55w-pecl-gearman.x86_64               1.1.2-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php55w-pecl-memcache.x86_64              3.0.8-2.w5                 webtatic-el5
php55w-pecl-xdebug.x86_64                2.2.5-1.w5                 webtatic-el5
php55w-pgsql.x86_64                      5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-recode.x86_64                     5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-snmp.x86_64                       5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-soap.x86_64                       5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-tidy.x86_64                       5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
php55w-xmlrpc.x86_64                     5.5.14-1.w5                webtatic-el5
```

Comment: I use webtatic, and they're on PHP 5.5.14 currently. Perhaps you're viewing an old yum cache? Is your `yum` command configured to use the `--cacheonly` option through a shell alias or wrapper script? Try forcing it to expire the cache: `yum clean expire-cache` and try again.

Comment: I am using the webtatic repo for el6, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: Thank you. I tried your suggestion, but the same thing happened. I also tried these commands to clean yum cache, such as: "su -c 'yum clean headers'", "su -c 'yum clean packages'", "yum clean all",...but it doesn't make the different things.

Comment: I just configured the el5 repo and tried `yum list` and I see that it includes "php55w-mysql.x86_64 5.5.14-1.w6". I don't know what the solution is, but it seems your system is not seeing the current or complete list of packages from webtatic.

Comment: I found the solution! First remove the old webtatic package, use  command: `rpm -e webtatic5-release-5.1-3.noarch` then install it again, and `yum  --enablerepo=webtatic-el5 list | grep php
` will list all my dream packages. Note that I must call `webtatic-el5`, not `webtatic` as normal. I don't know why, `webtatic.repo` is listed in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` but empty content (file size = 0). And there are two alt webtatic repos: `webtatic-archive`, `webtatic-testing`.

Comment: Congrats on finding the solution! The repo name is not the repo filename, I think it's the label in square brackets in the first line of the repo file.