# php55w not installed, CentOS 6.5

Tags: php-5.5

I am installing php55 based on the instructions here: [https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960582/php55w-mysql-not-listed-in-webtatic-repo)

after I run the "yum install php55w", it says NO package,

then I tried this command to list:  "yum  --enablerepo=webtatic list | grep php", I got this list which does not make any sense:

```
cups-php.x86_64                         1:1.4.2-52.el6_5.2             updates
eclipse-phpeclipse.noarch               1.2.1-6.el6                    epel
graphviz-php.x86_64                     2.26.0-10.el6                  base
nntpgrab-php.x86_64                     0.7.2-1.el6                    epel
remctl-php.x86_64                       3.8-2.el6                      epel
rrdtool-php.x86_64                      1.3.8-6.el6                    base
sphinx-php.x86_64                       2.0.8-1.el6                    epel
uuid-php.x86_64                         1.6.1-10.el6                   base
```

can any one help?

this not not work for me either:
[php55w-mysql not listed in webtatic repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960582/php55w-mysql-not-listed-in-webtatic-repo)

Answer (score 1):

The guide you linked to has the repo from el5, which would be CentOS 5.  If you install the webtatic repo for CentOS 6 instead, it will work, i.e.

```
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

and then install PHP 5.5 and any other modules, e.g.

```
yum install php55w php55w-{ldap,intl,xml,gd,pdo,pgsql}
```